# What's the event that should be triggered from ZK Teco terminal to winForms Application once a face recognition image is saved for a user

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am developing Time Attendance System by using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Its a Windows Forms Application, and for the time attendance terminal I am using ZK Teco (i Face 800) terminal
I already downloaded the zkemkeeper.dll library and added it to my project references. All its functions and events are working fine.

I am asking if there is an event should be triggered from the terminal to my application once i save a face recognition image of a user in that terminal?

For example when I save a fingerprint of a user inside the terminal, the terminal directly triggers this event inside my Windows Forms Application :
    OnEnrollFingerEx

Here is code that shows the IZKEM_Events inside zkemkeeper.dll library

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace zkemkeeper
{
[ComVisible(false)]
[ComEventInterface(typeof(_IZKEMEvents), 
typeof(_IZKEMEvents_EventProvider))]
[TypeLibType(16)]
public interface _IZKEMEvents_Event
{
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnAlarmEventHandler OnAlarm;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler OnAttTransaction;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler OnAttTransactionEx;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler OnConnected;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnDeleteTemplateEventHandler OnDeleteTemplate;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler OnDisConnected;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnDoorEventHandler OnDoor;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnEMDataEventHandler OnEMData;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler OnEmptyCard;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerEventHandler OnEnrollFinger;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler OnEnrollFingerEx;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler OnFinger;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler OnFingerFeature;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler OnHIDNum;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnKeyPressEventHandler OnKeyPress;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler OnNewUser;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler OnVerify;
    event _IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler OnWriteCard;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance and best regards to all of you,,

Answer (score 0):

could it be possible that you, your company has a newer model of security which the dll not yet supports, or is this another version. because it would obviously be in documentation.